# Custom view resolver missing in Spring test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I am doing integration tests of my Spring web app and need to verify generated HTML pages.
I am testing withing full Web Application Context but there is a problem with custom view resolver (JTwig). Here is my code:

Test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
    @WebAppConfiguration
    public class FrontControllerIntegrationTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;

    @InjectMocks
    private FrontController frontController = new FrontController();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void mainSearchPage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/search/ww/en/altivar"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(view().name("searchResults"))
               .andExpect(model().attribute("idolResponse", isA(SearchResults.class)))
               .andExpect(model().attribute("numberOfPages", is(188)))
               .andExpect(model().attribute("stateId", isNull()));
    }

}
```

Custom view resolver:

```
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer {
...
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    JtwigViewResolver view = new JtwigViewResolver();
    view.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    view.setSuffix(".twig");
    return view;
}
```

Test fails with error:

```
Caused by: com.lyncode.jtwig.exception.ResourceException: Resource /WEB-INF/templates/searchResults.twig not found
    at com.lyncode.jtwig.resource.WebJtwigResource.retrieve(WebJtwigResource.java:36)
    at com.lyncode.jtwig.parser.parboiled.JtwigContentParser.parse(JtwigContentParser.java:62)
    ... 54 more
```

After more digging I know where the exception is thrown:

```
@Override
public InputStream retrieve() throws ResourceException {
    InputStream resourceAsStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(url);
    if (resourceAsStream == null) throw new ResourceException("Resource "+url+" not found");
    return resourceAsStream;
}
```

Where `servletContext` is `org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example: https://github.com/lyncode/jtwig-examples/blob/master/simple-webapp/src/test/java/com/lyncode/jtwig/example/ControllerTest.java

Note that the annotation @WebAppConfiguration, by default, assumes the execution directory to be the directory of your project and also that, it follows the default maven structure.

If you are running the test on some IDE it might not conform to this. Also, if your project does not follow the default maven structure, you'll need to pass the webapp directory location in the annotation.

Check the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/test/context/web/WebAppConfiguration.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably your resources are not copied from 'main' dir to 'test'. Try to run tests and go to $PROJECT_HOME/target/$PROJECT_NAME - is WEB_INF folder with templates there (in case its maven project, im not sure if gradle uses the same structure)?

If they are not there then maybve you have to define  node in your pom.xml. Take a look at documentation:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/testResources-mojo.html

Comment: I have tried different directories with <testResources> but without success. I can confirm that templates are copied to target dir when building artifact, but after cleaning target and running search it's still empty, like test would not use it.